# "It was an admission that all might not be right between them." What does this sentence mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am reading "Ender's Game", and I can't figure out what it means when I come across this sentence.

Here is the context:

> “Here, snag my hand!” Alai called.
>
> Ender held out his hand. Alai took the shock of impact and helped Ender make a  fairly gentle landing against the wall.
>
> “That’s good,” Ender said. “We ought to practice that kind of thing.”
>
> “That’s what I thought, only everybody’s turning to butter out there,” Alai said. “What happens if we get out there together? We should be able to shove each other in opposite directions.”
>
> “Yeah.”
>
> “OK?”
>
> **It was an admission that all might not be right between them.** Is it OK for us to do something together? Ender’s answer was to take Alai by the wrist and get ready to push off.”

I think "all might not be right" could be a idiom, but find nothing when I google "all might not be right".

Or, "all might not be right" is a specific use of "all not" phrase?
It is "all something might not be right between them. And that something is left out?
And I can replace "all something might not be right" with "something might not all be right" without changing the meaning of the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three things going on here which may be confusing you.

1. The final clause *that all might not be right with them* acts as the **complement** to the noun *admission*.

   You probably know that many verbs take complements—direct objects, indirect objects, predicative complements, and so forth—but you may not be aware that adjectives and nouns take complements, too. The adjective *ready*, for instance takes two sorts of complement: preposition phrases (PP) with *for* (*ready for dinner*) and infinitive clauses (IC) (*ready to have dinner*). The noun *idea* takes (among other things) PP with *of* and *for* (*the idea of having dinner*, *an idea for dinner*) and what are sometimes called ‘content clauses’ (CC) headed by *that* (‘an idea that dinner will be soon*).

   Nouns which are derived from transitive verbs are particularly likely to take complements to express the object of the action, and that is the case with *admission*: it is derived from *admit* and both the verb and the noun may take a CC as complement:

   > He admitted his guilt.
   >   He admitted **that he was guilty**.
   >   ... his admission **that he was guilty** ...

   So in your example, *that all might not be right with them* is what Alai admitted.
2. In the complement clause, *all* acts as the subject with the syntactic force of a **noun phrase**<sup>†</sup> and the meaning ‘everything’. This use was once common, but it’s relatively rare today, when we mostly use *all* as a quantifier or an adverbial.  *All is...* and *all are...* have a distinctly literary ring; if you Google-book them you will find that most 21st-century hits are religious or philosophical, or historical reprints.

   This is probably why you are more comfortable with “all something might ... ” or “... might not all be right”. But ‘nominal’ *all* still hangs around in a handful of fixed phrases such as *all is well* and *all is lost*—and *all is right* with such-and-such. *All is right with them* means *Everything’s OK with them*.
3. ‘Nominal’ *all* behaves oddly with negation. If you want to negate a statement about *every X* or *everyX* or with *all X*, particularly if you need to make it clear that what you mean is that you are asserting that the statement is not true of *{all/every}* X but only of *some* X, you put your *not* in front of *all/every*:

   > Not all pronouns have a distinct objective form.
   >   Not everybody loves Raymond.

   But old-fashioned ‘nominal’ *all* carries along an older, less specific negative, with *not* after the verb. *All might not be right* means

> It was possible that not everything was right between them—some things might be wrong.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>I’m deliberately weaseling here in saying ‘syntactic force’, because grammarians are undecided whether to call this use a pronoun, a noun, or a ‘fused-head determiner’. Don’t worry about it; it doesn’t really matter what you call it as long as you understand what it’s doing.</sub>

Comment: Create explanation, clear and very thorough. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> It was an admission that all might not be right between them.

The meaning is

> It was the admission of the possibility that **not everything** in their relationships was right.

Or

> It was an admission that, probably, **not all** was right between them.

Technically speaking, **all** is a determiner (according to Wiktionary), although I was tempted to call it a noun..

If we change the word order to

> It was an admission that **might** not all be right between them.

Then we would be tempted to read **might** according to its [noun sense "power, strength"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/might#Noun), not according to its modal verb sense. To add to that, the clause beginning with "that" would then have no sense.

Maybe someone else will shed more light on this *all*.

Comment: I've googled something up, and find out that the "all not" can be regenerate using "not all", based on that, can I replace "all might not be right" to "might not all be right" with out changing the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: No, if you rephrase to "It was an admission that might not all be right between them", the original meaning will be lost.

Comment: And what is the difference?

Comment: Oh, all is a noun here.

Comment: @Rui - I first edited my answer to point out that **all** is a noun, but upon [a closer look at Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all#Determiner), **all** seems to be a determiner, by linguistical standards. Example: "A good time was had by all." Live and learn!

Comment: But in the ODE(Oxford Dictionary of English), the meaning everyone resides in noun category.

Comment: @Rui - I'm not sure then. Maybe different dictionaries reflect differing views.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19250/discussion-between-rui-and-copperkettle).